# How do I make it so only numbers 0-9 can be entered into prompt window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prompt

I need to be able to only enter the numbers 1 through to 9 in my prompt window. At the moment, I can enter any character I want and it will still work. How do I restrict this to numbers only? Here is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Start Game</button>
<button>Stop Game</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<p><font size="20">Your chosen number is:</font></p>
<span id="number"></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<p><font size="20">Your score so far is:</font></p>
<br/>
<span id="gamedisplay"></span>
<span id="gamedisplay2"></span>
<span id="gamedisplay3"></span>
<span id="gamedisplay4"></span>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var integer = prompt("Please enter an integer between 1 and 9");
if (integer != null) {
  document.getElementById("gamedisplay").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  document.getElementById("gamedisplay2").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  document.getElementById("gamedisplay3").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  document.getElementById("gamedisplay4").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 }
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prompt cannot be restricted during entry; it's pretty bare-bones.  You can only validate what was entered.  If you need to restrict entry while the user is still typing, you'll have to make a modal window and handle entry yourself.  That's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

[prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns a string, you need to check whether that string is a number or not. [Number.isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) could help, or check against a regexp, or parseInt()?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNumber () {
  let someNumber = prompt('enter a number from 1 to 9');
  for(;;) {
    if (someNumber !== '' && typeof Number(someNumber) === 'number' && someNumber    < 10 && someNumber > 0){ 
    //do something here 
    return Number(someNumber);
}else{
    //do something else here
    someNumber = prompt('Please, enter a number from 1 to 9');
   } 
  }
}
```

here i check is that not an empty string and type of its value is a number, and that number is bigger than 0 and less than 10;
if all is ok, i return value and stop the loop, if not - asking one more time for number